# Having trouble with getting bat file to work, does anyone know what is wrong with this bat file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
cls
echo Date format = %date%
echo dd = %date:~0,2%
echo mm = %date:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~6,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %time%
echo hh = %time:~0,2%
echo mm = %time:~3,2%
echo ss = %time:~6,2%
echo.
set timestamp=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
F:\XAMPP\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -pABC123 database >"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\backups\database_file_%timestamp%.sql"
```

The bat file breaks when I add the timestamp variable. I have tried a few different things but I am unsure why adding the timestamp variable would break it.

Comment: Fist two steps to debugging a batch file 1) Don't use `ECHO OFF`. 2) Run the batch file from a cmd prompt instead of using your mouse to execute it.  This way you can see all of the verbose execution and the error messages it is generating.

Comment: What does *breaks* mean specifically?

Comment: Regardless of my previous comment it would be helpful to you to take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question.   Also, please be certain you are providing a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: I don't think this question should be tagged with "mysql".  This question does not really have anything to do with mysql specifically

Comment: It would help us if you also told us what was being output for `%date%` and `%time%` on your PC, for the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're extracting the wrong characters in the date variable. The date value includes a three-character day (`Mon 12/04/2021`) which you're not skipping, so you're extracting the wrong values for `yyyy`, `mm` and `dd`.

Try this:

```
cls
echo Date format = %date%
echo dd = %date:~4,2%
echo mm = %date:~7,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~10,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %time%
echo hh = %time:~0,2%
echo mm = %time:~3,2%
echo ss = %time:~6,2%
echo.
set timestamp=%date:~10,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
F:\XAMPP\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -pABC123 database >"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\backups\database_file_%timestamp%.sql"
```

Note that the date format is dependent on locale (and possibly Windows version). Most obviously the day and month will be interchanged between US English and UK English. Other languages will need to be adjusted for their specific formats.

Comment: That is not 100% correct.  The `%date%` variable is region and location specific.  It does not output the same for everyone.

Comment: @Squashman Noted. Comment to that effect added